# Convert intraday time series to daily

Tags: r, xts

I have been using to.daily from the xts package to achieve this, but since upgrading R have encountered a known bug in this function, so would like to find an alternative way.

I would like to use functions from Base R if possible. It looks like I can do it with aggregate. I have no idea how to get started, so any hints would be appreciated.

```
z <- read.csv("R H2007-EIR_5.csv", sep=",",  header=F)
names(z) <-c("date","time","open","high","low","close","volume")

> head(z,20)
         date  time   open   high    low  close volume
1  13/03/2007 09:10 107.66 107.66 107.66 107.66     10
2  13/03/2007 09:40 107.63 107.63 107.63 107.63     50
3  13/03/2007 09:45 107.64 107.64 107.64 107.64      8
4  13/03/2007 10:00 107.62 107.62 107.62 107.62      7
5  13/03/2007 10:45 107.64 107.65 107.64 107.65     94
6  13/03/2007 11:20 107.77 107.77 107.77 107.77      2
7  14/03/2007 09:00 108.00 108.00 108.00 108.00     10
8  14/03/2007 09:05 108.00 108.01 108.00 108.01     45
9  14/03/2007 11:15 108.05 108.05 108.05 108.05      5
10 14/03/2007 11:25 108.05 108.05 108.05 108.05      1
11 14/03/2007 11:40 108.10 108.10 108.10 108.10     25
12 14/03/2007 12:00 108.10 108.10 108.10 108.10      5
13 14/03/2007 12:30 108.05 108.05 108.05 108.05      5
14 14/03/2007 12:55 108.05 108.05 108.05 108.05    800
15 14/03/2007 13:05 108.02 108.02 108.02 108.02     89
16 14/03/2007 13:30 108.00 108.00 108.00 108.00      5
17 14/03/2007 14:25 107.95 107.95 107.95 107.95      5
18 14/03/2007 15:05 107.95 107.95 107.95 107.95      2
19 14/03/2007 16:00 108.01 108.01 108.01 108.01      6
20 15/03/2007 08:05 107.86 107.90 107.86 107.90      2

> dput(z)
    structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("13/03/2007", "14/03/2007", 
"15/03/2007", "16/03/2007", "19/03/2007", "20/03/2007", "21/03/2007", 
"22/03/2007", "23/03/2007", "26/03/2007", "27/03/2007", "28/03/2007"
), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 
26L, 6L, 7L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 42L, 46L, 
54L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 45L, 46L, 11L, 44L, 55L, 11L, 23L, 31L, 32L, 
48L, 10L, 43L, 1L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 31L, 53L, 54L, 36L, 46L, 47L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 12L, 16L, 30L, 40L, 19L, 31L, 38L, 39L, 4L, 27L, 
31L, 33L, 41L, 43L, 50L, 52L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L), .Label = c("08:00", "08:05", "08:10", "08:30", 
"08:55", "09:00", "09:05", "09:10", "09:15", "09:30", "09:40", 
"09:45", "10:00", "10:05", "10:15", "10:25", "10:30", "10:35", 
"10:40", "10:45", "10:50", "10:55", "11:00", "11:10", "11:15", 
"11:20", "11:25", "11:40", "12:00", "12:05", "12:15", "12:20", 
"12:30", "12:55", "13:05", "13:25", "13:30", "13:35", "13:55", 
"14:00", "14:15", "14:25", "14:30", "14:35", "14:45", "15:05", 
"15:10", "15:15", "15:20", "15:25", "15:30", "15:40", "15:55", 
"16:00", "16:10"), class = "factor"), open = c(107.66, 107.63, 
107.64, 107.62, 107.64, 107.77, 108, 108, 108.05, 108.05, 108.1, 
108.1, 108.05, 108.05, 108.02, 108, 107.95, 107.95, 108.01, 107.86, 
107.86, 107.88, 107.8, 107.79, 107.78, 107.64, 107.75, 107.61, 
107.6, 107.55, 107.55, 107.48, 107.4, 107.43, 107.39, 107.48, 
107.53, 107.56, 107.47, 107.39, 107.39, 107.37, 107.3, 107.3, 
107.29, 107.29, 107.29, 107.16, 107.13, 107.11, 107.06, 106.8, 
106.72, 106.7, 106.72, 106.62, 106.72, 106.58, 106.58, 106.62, 
106.66, 106.73, 106.67, 106.61, 106.6, 106.6, 106.57, 106.61, 
106.6, 106.59, 106.6, 106.62, 106.65), high = c(107.66, 107.63, 
107.64, 107.62, 107.65, 107.77, 108, 108.01, 108.05, 108.05, 
108.1, 108.1, 108.05, 108.05, 108.02, 108, 107.95, 107.95, 108.01, 
107.9, 107.86, 107.89, 107.8, 107.79, 107.78, 107.64, 107.75, 
107.61, 107.6, 107.55, 107.55, 107.48, 107.4, 107.43, 107.39, 
107.48, 107.53, 107.56, 107.47, 107.39, 107.39, 107.37, 107.3, 
107.3, 107.29, 107.29, 107.29, 107.16, 107.13, 107.11, 107.06, 
106.8, 106.72, 106.7, 106.72, 106.62, 106.72, 106.58, 106.58, 
106.62, 106.66, 106.73, 106.67, 106.62, 106.6, 106.6, 106.57, 
106.61, 106.6, 106.63, 106.6, 106.65, 106.65), low = c(107.66, 
107.63, 107.64, 107.62, 107.64, 107.77, 108, 108, 108.05, 108.05, 
108.1, 108.1, 108.05, 108.05, 108.02, 108, 107.95, 107.95, 108.01, 
107.86, 107.86, 107.88, 107.8, 107.79, 107.78, 107.64, 107.75, 
107.61, 107.6, 107.55, 107.55, 107.48, 107.29, 107.43, 107.39, 
107.48, 107.53, 107.56, 107.47, 107.39, 107.39, 107.37, 107.3, 
107.3, 107.29, 107.29, 107.29, 107.16, 107.13, 107.11, 107.06, 
106.8, 106.72, 106.7, 106.72, 106.62, 106.72, 106.58, 106.58, 
106.62, 106.66, 106.73, 106.67, 106.61, 106.6, 106.6, 106.57, 
106.61, 106.6, 106.59, 106.6, 106.61, 106.65), close = c(107.66, 
107.63, 107.64, 107.62, 107.65, 107.77, 108, 108.01, 108.05, 
108.05, 108.1, 108.1, 108.05, 108.05, 108.02, 108, 107.95, 107.95, 
108.01, 107.9, 107.86, 107.89, 107.8, 107.79, 107.78, 107.64, 
107.75, 107.61, 107.6, 107.55, 107.55, 107.48, 107.3, 107.43, 
107.39, 107.48, 107.53, 107.56, 107.47, 107.39, 107.39, 107.37, 
107.3, 107.3, 107.29, 107.29, 107.29, 107.16, 107.13, 107.11, 
107.06, 106.8, 106.72, 106.7, 106.72, 106.62, 106.72, 106.58, 
106.58, 106.62, 106.66, 106.73, 106.67, 106.61, 106.6, 106.6, 
106.57, 106.61, 106.6, 106.61, 106.6, 106.65, 106.65), volume = c(10L, 
50L, 8L, 7L, 94L, 2L, 10L, 45L, 5L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 5L, 800L, 89L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 178L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 50L, 
44L, 100L, 400L, 91L, 1L, 100L, 100L, 3L, 1L, 79L, 21L, 28L, 
80L, 20L, 20L, 31L, 49L, 5L, 1L, 25L, 1L, 20L, 284L, 2368L, 454L, 
18L, 43L, 11L, 547L, 18L, 1L, 3L, 253L, 200L, 5L, 35L, 30L, 50L, 
50L, 172L, 99L, 1728L, 82L)), .Names = c("date", "time", "open", 
"high", "low", "close", "volume"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-73L))
```

Desired output:

```
         date   open   high    low  close
 1 13/03/2007 107.66 107.77 107.62 107.77
 2 14/03/2007 108.00 108.10 107.95 108.01
 3 15/03/2007 107.86 107.90 107.86 107.90
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question? I don't know what `to.daily` does.

Comment: I would like to replicate the functionality of to.period, ie from a dataframe containing intraday observations, create a new dataframe with daily observations.  Open would then be the first observation of open for each date, close the last observation of close for each date, and high/low the maximum/minimum of high/low for each date.

Comment: Thanks. Could you edit your post to show the output you require?

Comment: @HestonGlobal , just curious, Why do you want a base solution? I mean why not to use `xts` package for example.

Comment: @agstudy it is because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110531/incorrect-date-alignment-using-xts-to-period

Comment: @HestonGlobal You can see my solution ( it can be also a workaround to the previous question (xts bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this?

```
o <- aggregate(data = z, open ~ date, head, 1)
o$max <- aggregate(data = z, high ~ date, max)$high
o$min <- aggregate(data = z, low ~ date, min)$low
o$close <- aggregate(data = z, close ~ date, tail, 1)$close

#         date   open    max    min  close
# 1 13/03/2007 107.66 107.77 107.62 107.77
# 2 14/03/2007 108.00 108.10 107.95 108.01
# 3 15/03/2007 107.86 107.90 107.86 107.90
```

Comment: Thank you this works well.  Mind explaining why prefer the solution by plannapus?

Comment: He's wrapped it in a nice little function that saves quite a bit of time if you've a lot of data. Otherwise, I don't see a difference.

Comment: I have decided to use this one as I like the simplicity of it and can see myself incorporating aggregate in the future.  As far as speed goes, it seems comparable to the to.period function in xts.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
todaily <- function(z){
    zperiod<-split(z,cut(strptime(paste(z$date, z$time), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), "day"))
    zperiod<-zperiod[sapply(zperiod,nrow)!=0]
    res<-do.call(rbind,lapply(zperiod, 
                  function(x)c(x$open[1],
                               max(c(x$open,x$max, x$min,x$close), na.rm=TRUE),     
                               min(c(x$open,x$max, x$min,x$close), na.rm=TRUE), 
                               x$close[nrow(x)])))
    colnames(res)<-c("open","max","min","close")
    res
    }
todaily(z)
             open    max    min  close
2007-03-13 107.66 107.77 107.62 107.77
2007-03-14 108.00 108.10 107.95 108.01
2007-03-15 107.86 107.90 107.86 107.90
```

Of course you can modify it for any period of time that `cut.POSIXt` can handle (see `?cut.POSIXt`):

```
toperiod <- function(z, period="day"){
    zperiod<-split(z,cut(strptime(paste(z$date, z$time), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), period))
    zperiod<-zperiod[sapply(zperiod,nrow)!=0]
    res<-do.call(rbind,lapply(zperiod, 
                  function(x)c(x$open[1],
                               max(c(x$open,x$max, x$min,x$close), na.rm=TRUE),     
                               min(c(x$open,x$max, x$min,x$close), na.rm=TRUE), 
                               x$close[nrow(x)])))
    colnames(res)<-c("open","max","min","close")
    res
    }
```

Using the full dataset you uploaded, here's what this last function can do:

```
toperiod(z, "weeks")
                      open    max    min  close
2007-03-12 00:00:00 107.66 108.10 107.62 107.75
2007-03-19 00:00:00 107.61 107.61 107.06 107.06
2007-03-26 01:00:00 106.80 106.80 106.57 106.65

toperiod(z, "2 weeks")
                      open   max    min  close
2007-03-12 00:00:00 107.66 108.1 107.06 107.06
2007-03-26 01:00:00 106.80 106.8 106.57 106.65
```

Comment: (+1) *much* better than mine!

Comment: I get this error message `Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("open", "max", "min", "close" : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(c(x$open, x$max, x$min, x$close), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(c(x$open, x$max, x$min, x$close), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(c(x$open, x$max, x$min, x$close), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: Could you show what the actual data you inputted to this function looks like? With `str` for instance.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `> str(z)
'data.frame': 73 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ date  : Factor w/ 12 levels "13/03/2007","14/03/2007",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ time  : Factor w/ 55 levels "08:00","08:05",..: 8 11 12 13 20 26 6 7 25 27 ...
 $ open  : num  108 108 108 108 108 ...
 $ high  : num  108 108 108 108 108 ...
 $ low   : num  108 108 108 108 108 ...
 $ close : num  108 108 108 108 108 ...
 $ volume: int  10 50 8 7 94 2 10 45 5 1 ...`

Comment: Is there some days without entries?

Comment: I think that was the issue. I corrected the function to prevent this kind of error.

Comment: Thankyou, there are days without entries (usually weekends).  I edited my question to include the full data set as the date is not matching correctly on the last 3 observations.  The output for 2007-03-25 should be 2007-03-26, and the last 2 observations are also offset by one day.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that mix `xts` and `base` functions.

First I create , my xts object.

```
INDEX <- strptime(paste(dat[,1],dat[,2],sep=' '),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
dat.xts <- xts(dat[,-c(1,2)],INDEX)
```

The final solution is a subset of this xts object. I use `endpoints` to get a subset of the final data but with the wrong coredata.

```
dat.xts[INDEX,-c(5)]
                      open   high    low  close
2007-03-13 11:20:00 107.77 107.77 107.77 107.77
2007-03-14 16:00:00 108.01 108.01 108.01 108.01
2007-03-15 08:05:00 107.86 107.90 107.86 107.90
```

Now I compute the coredata, using `lapply`

```
xx <- lapply(1:(length(INDEX) - 1), function(y) {
  xi <- as.data.frame(dat.xts[(INDEX[y] + 1):INDEX[y + 1]])
    res <- c(
      xi$open[1],
      max(c(xi$open,x$max, xi$min,xi$close), na.rm=TRUE),     
      min(c(xi$open,x$max, xi$min,xi$close), na.rm=TRUE), 
      x$close[nrow(xi)])
  })

coredata(res) <- do.call(rbind,xx)
```

To get the desired result:

```
                       open   high    low  close
2007-03-13 11:20:00 107.66 107.77 107.62 107.77
2007-03-14 16:00:00 108.00 108.10 107.95 108.05
2007-03-15 08:05:00 107.86 107.90 107.86 107.66
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I got an error message when I executed it, so have decided to go with the above solution.  `Error in (index[y] + 1):index[y + 1] : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In (index[y] + 1):index[y + 1] :
  numerical expression has 9 elements: only the first used`

Comment: @HestonGlobal you get the error why you apply it on all your data or on the z given on the question?

Comment: @GSee thanks for the edit. Does this solution is OK for you or you find the same OP problem.

Comment: @agstudy, I can empathize with the OP. [The bug](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2577&group_id=118&atid=516) sucks.  But, it's a timezone issue that can probably be worked around by being careful to include `tz` in an `as.Date` call.  Unfortunately I can't replicate the problem in my timezone without more info than just the data that the OP provided.